# Embedding First External Image in Webpage

Tags: css, image, embed

I want to embed the first image within a div of a page, e.g. the first image in `.img-comic-container` on dilbert.com. I tried this:

```js
fetch("https://cors.now.sh/http://dilbert.com")
.then((res)=> res.text())
.then((res)=> {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(res, "text/html");
  var img = doc.querySelector('.img-comic-container .img-comic');
  document.querySelector("#dilbert").src = img.src;
});
```

```html
<div id="place">
  <img id="dilbert" />
</div>
```

Without luck, though. Is there an alternative to cors.now.sh?

Comment: Seems like cors.now.sh [is down](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/cors.now.sh)
Maybe you can check out [scraperapi](https://www.scraperapi.com/)

Comment: Hi, thank you; if you could kindly submit that as an answer with an example I'll gladly accept it as the solving solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like cors.now.sh is down or out of serivce. You can use an alternative https://www.scraperapi.com/.